# log4j.properties on a library

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a library that provides a specific log service that is shared across multiple projects and this project uses log4j to generate the file. In a web client application I have this service project as a dependency, but this web project also has a log4j.properties file. How can I do to use two separate log4j.properties settings?

Example:

```
SiemLogger logger = SiemLoggerFactory.getLogger();
logger.log(obj); // uses the library service, that generates an output file
```

And:

```
Logger logger = WebLog.getLogger();
logger.info("same information"); // uses the web application log4j configurations
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I created a CustomFileAppender that takes the information to build the log and append it to my Logger. This class extends the RollingFileAppender of log4j implementation. That works for me!